# regex java parsing

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, text

I'm using Java to try and parse a file. I'm looking for ages of people in the document. Here are the examples I've seen so far:

> 49-years-old
>
> 31 years old
>
> , 26,
>
> , 45,
>
> 30s,
>
> late thirties,

Basically, I need to extract all the ages of people in the file. I'm not sure what would be the right regex expressions that would hit those parameters. For numbers like "thirties", what's the best way to do all the number series "forties", "fifties", etc?

Comment: Perhaps you are using the wrong tool for the task. What is your success rate with the above regex-s? I would imagine that `, 26,` would yield a lot of false positives as well

Comment: You need to check out natural language processing packages. Regex alone can only give you a bunch of random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question from my CS friend at Stanford.

Why manually figure out all the regex codes, when you can get it generated for you?

http://txt2re.com/index-java.php3

This website makes it extremely easy to pick what pieces of information you are trying to extract. It successfully found all the possibilities of things I could want to extract from a string, and I simply clicked which pieces I wanted.

The tool beat everything else I found about regex.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go with regex in this case, in this caes. I would rather build a function that will scan through the input. I that it would be more dependable. Regex, could get a little messy sometimes.

Comment: How do I handle the numbers though? Let's say the ages can be from 20 to 100? Would I have a loop that check for every single age and phrasing of ages?

There's got to be a better way.

Comment: It all depends on how advanced you are in java. What you can do is check for what data type did the user input. Then what you can do is define your own regex function for those specific data types. But even then, it might be better to build some kind of comparison mechanism. You dont really need to use a loop, what I would make is a list, or a vector, I believe they have a function called "contains", or something like that all you have to do is pass the input of the user into a vector containing all the possible ages. I hope this helps, if you want some sample code let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For all your example inputs *except* the last one, it is straightforward to extract the age using something like the below pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^\\d]*(\\d+)[^\\d]*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("30s"); // 49-years-old, 31 years old
if (matcher.matches()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

But when the age is written in words, there is no straightforward solution and probably your pattern (or whatever algorithm you will do to extract this); has to evolve with time, because people might einput their age in different *styles* that you have to accommodate in.